# how to stop backgroundworker while running

Tags: c#

I am new to c sharp .
I have created an windows form application .
my application works fine.
i want to cancel the BackgroundWorker while running. i mean i want to completely stop the BackgroundWorker Process.
I am using this code to cancel the application,
1 )first i used

```
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Dispose();
    }
```

but it doesnot stop . then i used

```
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgBackfill1.CancelAsync();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

but when i exit the application it writes the files in G:\Drive .
can anyone please say me how can i stop writing the files in G:\Drive and stop the BackgroundWorker Process Completely.

Thanks if someone Helps me.

Answer (score 5):

Backgroundworkers worker method must know that there is cancellation pending, so only then it can cancel.

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
        }
    }
}
```

So, when you set CancelAsync, you set Cancellation pending. But you need also take care in DoWork method for that property - cancel job as soon as possible. See sample at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In your "DoWork" routine, you can check for the worker thread (lets call it worker1) with worker1.CancellationPending, if its true, then its tried to be cancelled, if you test for this in your itterative code within and obviously cease to continue processing, and set e.Cancel=true at the end, you will have successfully checked and processed the cancelling of your background worker.

Comment: when i am adding e.cancel its saying to set you are missing assembly reference can u pls say me what is the reference i need to add in wfa

Comment: If you look at VikciaR's post, the DoWorkEventArgs, contain a .Cancel, the using would be System.ComponentModel

Answer (score 1):

Your Backgroundworker has to be programmed to be cancellable. First set the worker cancelable:

```
 var bg= new BackgroundWorker();
 bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Then in your worker loop check the `CancellationPending` flag of the `BackgroundWorker` class to see when you should exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) property when you initialize the `BackgroundWorker` component, and before you call `RunWorkerAsync`. So, for example:

```
MyWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
MyWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
MyWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
MyWorker.DoWork += DoWorkEventHandler;
MyWorker.ProgressChanged += WorkerProgressChanged;
MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```